# Entering 2 values until a specific character key is pressed in C++?

Tags: c++, variables, input, int

I have a C++ program, where I want to read 2 values until a specific character key is pressed - in this case '0'. I would like to ask how can I accomplish that in C++ without complicating the program too much?
Thanks in advance.

Pseudocode:

```
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int a,b;
    int main(){
        while ('0' is not pressed) {
            cin>>a>>b;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can check if `a` or `b` is `0`, but there's no standard C++ way of checking individual key-presses. For that you need to use operating-system dependent code.

Comment: What if the user enters "10" for a or b?

Comment: Could do `for(;cin;) { cin >> a; if (a == 0) break; cin >> b; if (b == 0) break; }`

Answer (score 0):

If your on windows, you could do
`if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_A) && GetAsyncKeyState(VK_B)) { //run subroutine }`
as a quick and easy way of capturing keyboard input.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this:

```
while(1)
{
  cin>>a;
  if(a != 0)  cin>>b;
  else break;
  if(b == 0)  break;
}
```